# C# WindowsForm Font class, I would like to know the difference between the two codes

Tags: c#

I want to change the font in bold.
so,

```
Font rtboxfont = richtextbox1.SelectionFont;
rtboxfont = new Font(rtboxfont.Name,rtboxfont.Size,FontStyle.Bold);
```

but This code is not getting to work.

To work...

```
richtextbox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richtextbox1.Name,richtextbox1.Size,FontStyle.Bold);
```

I would like to know the difference between the two codes.

Answer (score 2):

`richtextbox1` and `rtboxfont` are different objects; they just both happen to have `Name` and `Size` properties that mean different things.

You were close on the first attempt, but you need to set the `SelectionFont` property; not just change the font variable that was storing it:

```
Font rtboxfont = richtextbox1.SelectionFont;
richtextbox1.SelectionFont = new Font(rtboxfont.Name,rtboxfont.Size,FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question Answered with the [Green Checkmark](http://i.imgur.com/FRNb0ey.jpg)